# Blazor WASM AuthenticationState using AAD - Claims null until Refresh

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

New to Blazor and have been doing a hatchet job to get things working how I want.

I am using Blazor WASM  with AAD for Authentication created based on this document [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). I implemented the SecureAccountFactory class from the example and call a db where I get the associated user based on the AAD Guid, then add everything into Claims.

```
public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(SecureUserAccount account,
    RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
{
    var initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);
    if (initialUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)initialUser.Identity;

        var claims = userIdentity.Claims;

        var principalId = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "oid").First();

        //Get some user info from SQL
        var User = await _UserService.Get(principalId.Value);

        //Get user Roles from SQL and add to Claims
        var UsersInRoles = await _UsersInRoleService.RolesByUserId(principalId.Value);

        //Add the ClientId to Claims
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("clientId", User.ClientId.ToString()));

        foreach (var userrole in UsersInRoles)
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", userrole.Role.Name));
        }

    }
    return initialUser;
}
```

I then have a Profile Component that appears on every page as part of the MainLayout which should have some info about the current user, so I made a static class to retrieve this info.

```
public static class UserHelper
{
    public static async Task<CurrentUserClaims> GetCurrentUserClaims(Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask)
    {
        AuthenticationState authenticationState;

        authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var AuthenticationStateUser = authenticationState.User;

        var user = authenticationState.User;

        var claims = user.Claims;
        var clientClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "clientId").First();
        var principalId = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "oid").First();

        return new CurrentUserClaims
        {
            ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(clientClaim.Value),
            PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(principalId.Value),
            user = user
        };
    }
}
```

In my ProfileComponent, I call CascadingParameter and then onParametersSet I query my Static class for the info from the current logged in user

```
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

private string profilePath;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    CurrentUserClaims UserClaims = await UserHelper.GetCurrentUserClaims(authenticationStateTask);

    var principal = UserClaims.PrincipalId;
    //... do stuff
}
```

The above all works, after a Refresh or once I route to any other page.  The initial Load, after login on the home page shows that the below line always fails with 'Sequence contains no elements'

```
var clientClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "clientId").First();
```

I am using Authorize to protect the pages and I will eventually be using the Roles to determine what to display to the user.

A: Surely there's a better way of doing the above.  There are lots and lots of articles on creating a custom Auth which inherits AuthenticationState but every one I've seen adds the Claims manually as a fake user, so I don't see how to access the actual Claims.

B: I'm wondering if just using LocalStorage for the User info might be a simpler way to go but is it considered 'safe' or best practice?

Any pointers to a solution are appreciated.

Comment: The MSDocs reference is the authentication and authorization overview.   There' no reference to a `SecureAccountFactory`, and I can't find any reference to a `SecureAccountFactory` anywhere.  I suspect `CreateUserAsync` get's used somewhere, but I can't see where in the code provided?

Comment: Sorry - I believe the code is a mix of this 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and this

https://dev.to/kasuken/securing-a-blazor-webassembly-hosted-apps-with-azure-active-directory-part-2-1ppd

Comment: I've not specifically done that before.  I can't see what you problem is, but I can see you are using a component to get and hold data.  You should consider holding your user data in a DI Scoped Service object and then accessing that from you display components.  Here's a similar question I answered earlier today that shows how this can be done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293173/user-specific-setting-cached-in-a-blazor-server-application.